# error when installing realtek wifi driver

Tags: command-line, permissions, make

hello I encountered this error when trying to install realtek wifi driver:

```
find /lib/modules/4.19.2-041902-generic -name "r8188ee_*.ko" -exec rm {} \;
install: cannot remove '/lib/modules/4.19.2-041902-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko': 
Permission denied
Makefile:48: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Comment: I suspect that you should have run *sudo* make install. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should **always** include the command you're running. In this example it's probably some installation script or make install.

Such scripts has to be run as root, as they attempt to write to system directories. The output is complaining that it cannot delete a file in `/lib`

Prepend whatever command you where running with `sudo` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword `sudo` before your command.
If It didn't worked.

Follow this lists of commands

```
sudo apt update
```

after that install git (if not previously installed):

```
sudo apt install -y dkms git
```

Clone this Directory "https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821..." or download it via browser:

```
git clone "https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821..."
```

Now install the driver:

```
cd rtl8821ce
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

After this command the wi-fi driver will show up

```
sudo modprobe 8821ce
```

If you downloaded via browser:

1. first extract the .zip file.
2. navigate into the rtl8821ce-master folder
3. Right click and select open in terminal
4. run the command `./dkms-install.sh` to install the driver
5. `sudo modprobe 8821ce` after this the wifi will start.

Hope it Helps